# Exporting tool to copy data by query between Elasticsearch 2.3.5 indexes

Tags: database, elasticsearch, bigdata, data-migration, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to extract some data using a query from one index in ElasticSearch (ES) and copy them in a temporary index in the same cluster. Then delete the index where I extracted the data from and rename the temporary one to the name of the deleted index.

I know that latest versions of ES provide a built-in `delete-by-query` but I'm tied to ES v2.3.5 which provide same functionality by installing `delete-by-query` plugin, but the problem is we have more than 20 nodes where we will have to install the plugin and then make a full cluster restart which we want to avoid.

After some research here in SO and by googling, I found an interesting scripting tool, [ElasticDump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump)

And also it seems interesting [ElasticSearch-Exporting](https://github.com/mallocator/Elasticsearch-Exporter)

But I would like some **opinions** from someone who already used some of them or **some other interesting options**.

I have to do the same operation for around 100 indexes: extract data for index1 -> copy those data to a temporary index -> delete index1 - rename temporary index to index1, so tools which can automatize the process are welcome. Anyway, I know that I could create a bash script using for instance, `ElasticDump` to repeat the process in each of those 100 indexes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you come across the _reindex API? If Yes, what is it that you find lacking in it to solve your problem?

Comment: Oooops, I knew about reindex API, but I thought was included from 2.4v, not in 2.3v, I just checked it out. Please, can you add an answer with your comment above, so in case no better answer I would accept yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [_reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) API to create the new index.

Create an alias on the old index and use that alias in your applications. When you want to create the new index, just reindex the old one into a new index with a different name. Once the _reindex completes, you can remove the alias from the old index and add it on the new index, in one atomic operation. Like so:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index1" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
        { "add" : { "index2" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } }
    ]
}'
```

This should ensure that you don't have a downtime during the index switching process. After switching the alias, you can delete the old index whenever you want.
See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html